# Security risks introduced when moving from a three tier to a two tier architecture

Tags: firewalls, vulnerability, .net, threat-mitigation, sql-server

I host several .net web applications using a standard three tier architecture with web servers located in a demilitarised zone.

I have been asked to host a two tier .net web application where the web server connects directly to the database.

Web sites, application services and databases use shared infrastructure and typically sit side by site.

What vulnerabilities are introduced by opening firewall holes directly to the database server and what measures can I take to migrate the risk?

Comment: There is something I didn't got there, in your three tiers architecture, what kind of client do you have ? Web pages ? Desktop application ?

Comment: Sorry. Standard asp mvc -> wcf -> sql.